# Azure Shared Website billing

Tags: azure-web-app-service

My shared instance website is costing about £20 GBP per month, and this is detailed as 'Compute Hours' in my bill.

[According to Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/09/17/announcing-great-improvements-to-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx)
"You pay for a shared mode web-site using the standard “pay as you go” model that we support with other features of Windows Azure (meaning no up-front costs, and you pay only for the hours that the feature is enabled).  A web-site running in shared mode costs only 1.3 cents/hr during the preview (so on average $9.36/month)."

According to the [azure pricing calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) a site on a shared instance should cost $9.36.

According to the [Azure pricing details](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/)

> "Shared Instance Model
>
> The shared instance model provides support for custom domain names, 1
>   GB of storage, and unlimited outbound data transfer charged on the
>   terms of your Windows Azure subscription at the standard Pay-As-You-Go
>   rates. Up to three instances per Web site may be deployed at an
>   additional cost.
>
> Under the shared instance model, you will receive the following
>   benefits:
>
> The ability to assign your custom host or domain name Outbound traffic
>   charged at Pay-As-You-Go rates; unlimited inbound data transfer 1 GB
>   storage (shared by all sites) 20 MB of a third-party, MySQL database
>   Each Web site operated under the shared instance model will be charged
>   at $0.02 / hour (approx. $14.40  / month) per Web Site instance at
>   general availability. During preview, a 33% discount will be applied
>   for an effective monthly rate of $9.60 / month, per Web Site instance.
>   During preview, all paid shared instance hours will be billed using
>   the current Cloud Services small compute meter, except we will emit
>   1/9th of the Cloud Services small compute hours to deliver the
>   discounted pricing of $9.60 / month per Web Site instance. The monthly
>   calculation per paid shared Web Site instance is as follows: 720 hours
>   * 1/9 * $0.12 =$9.60."

So what I am misunderstanding? A shared website at the this moment in time (Jan 2013) should cost less than $10 per month.

**EDIT MORE INFO**
The price I am paying is exactly 3 times £9.60

Comment: I have a single shared website that costs me approx $9.60 per month.  Cant say whats wrong with yours.

Comment: Just contact https://manage.windowsazure.com/?getsupport=true .. without a look at your portal it will be hard for anyone an stackoverflow to help you.

Comment: I did, they said I had three instances running, but they couldn't tell me what site the instances were for. Confused myself massively now because I don't remember fiddling with the instance settings.

Comment: Under the **Scale** tab check the **instance count**

Comment: Check if you are using local storage too.